# How to draw this WPF Path in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, pathgeometry, figures

I have been struggling to convert this piece of WPF code to C#. I am relatively new to WPF, and I really hope someone can help me out here :)

```
    <Path Fill="Blue" Margin="15,15,15,15">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry"
                Center="10,100" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" />
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard>

                        <!-- Animates the ellipse along the path. -->
                        <PointAnimationUsingPath
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Center"
                            Duration="0:0:5" 
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                            <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                <PathGeometry 
                                    Figures="M 10,100 C 35,0 135,0 160,100 135,0 35,0 10,100"
                                />
                            </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                        </PointAnimationUsingPath>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

I seemed to get along just fine until I got to the PathGeometry Figures... If anyone can supply me with a C# code snippet of this WPF code, it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend reading following msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).

```
"M 10,100 C 35,0 135,0 160,100 135,0 35,0 10,100"
```

Means following: start at (10,100). Add "cubic Bezier curve" ending at 10,100 with control points (35,0), (135,0), (160,100), (135,0), (35,0).

As I understand it. Such text should be easy to render into PathSegmentCollection.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for: [PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimationusingpath.pathgeometry%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). There's a detailed example of how to solve your problem, that shows how to use a PointAnimationUsingPath object to animate a Point along a curved path. For a [complete sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771534%28v=vs.90%29.aspx); and if you don't want to use Storyboard: [How to: Animate a Property Without Using a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753117%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Bear in mind that MSDN is stocked with examples and detailed [explanations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746916%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).